# reducing sections .text._ZN in elf

Tags: elf

I am trying to reduce the number of sections in the elf file,
there are many sections called .text._Z~ and .rodata._Z~, I tried with --remove-section but nothing worked out.

```
[1] .text               PROGBITS    4010000 80  19b3cb4 0   AX  0   0   128
[2] .text._ZN7HalMmio   PROGBITS    059c3cb4    19b3d34 00002c  0   AX  0   0   4
[3] .text._ZN7HalMmio   PROGBITS    059c3ce0    19b3d60 24  0   AX  0   0   4
[4] .text._ZN7HalMmio   PROGBITS    059c3d04    19b3d84 24  0   AX  0   0   4
[5] .text._ZN7HalMmio   PROGBITS    059c3d28    19b3da8 00002c  0   AX  0   0   4
[6] .text._ZN24Extern   PROGBITS    059c3d54    19b3dd4 44  0   AX  0   0   4
```

I need to combine all these sections in to single section `.text`.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to combine all these sections in to single section .text

No, you don't. If you succeed in doing that, your final executable will fail to link.

What you need to do is edit your question, and ask it in a way that provides details on *what you are actually trying to achieve*.